# Multiple dynamically created columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create multiple dynamic columns based on the number of items in a list. I can get the number of rows generated. I can also get everything to generate but not as columns. The end result should be each column side by side so that I can tab through each row by column. Ex

```
A    | B    | C    | D
-----+------+------+----
R1 4 | R1 2 | R2 3 | 9
```

Code:

```
cavlist = [row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6]
attrib = [a,b,c,d]

foreach (string cava in cavlist)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = cava.ToString();
    this.flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(lbl);

    TextBox txtserial = new TextBox();
    txtserial.Name = "cav" + cava;
    txtserial.Width = 100;
    this.flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(txtserial);
}

foreach(String attribs in attrib)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = attribs.ToString();

    this.flowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label);

    foreach (string cava in cavlist)
    {
        TextBox txtserial = new TextBox();
        txtserial.Name = "cav" + cava;
        txtserial.Width = 50;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using datagridview

```
foreach (string attrib in attribs)
        {
            string cat = attrib.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cat, cat);


        }

        foreach (string cava in cavlist)
        {

            TextBox txtserial = new TextBox();

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

        }
```